# How to get the cell indexes of a table?

Tags: javascript

I'm writing this javascript code, and I'm trying to get the indexes of each cells whenever I go over them with mouse.

```
const table = document.createElement("table");

document.body.appendChild(table);

let width = 10;
let height = 10;

table.innerHTML = "";
let content = "";

for (let i = 0; i < width; i++) {

    content += "<tr>";

    for (let j = 0; j < height; j++) {
        content += "<td></td>";
    }

    content += "</tr>";
}

table.innerHTML += content

const cell = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");

cell.addEventListener('mouseover', getIndex());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should wait until after you have populated your table before appending it to the body.

Then, as `getElementsByTagName` returns a nodelist, you need to iterate over it and attach an event listener to each cell. It's probably easier just get all of the cells, rather than rows at this point.

Then from within the event listener callback, you can access the cell index with `this.cellIndex`, and the row index with `this.parentNode.rowIndex`

```js
const table = document.createElement("table");

let width = 10;
let height = 10;

table.innerHTML = "";
let content = "";

for (let i = 0; i < width; i++) {
  content += "<tr>";

  for (let j = 0; j < height; j++) {
    content += "<td>X</td>";
  }

  content += "</tr>";
}

table.innerHTML += content;

document.body.appendChild(table);

const cells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");


Array.from(cells).forEach(cell => {
  cell.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    const rowIndex = this.parentNode.rowIndex
    const cellIndex = this.cellIndex
    console.log(`rowIndex: ${rowIndex}, cellIndex: ${cellIndex}`);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `mousemove` event handler, check if `e.target` matches the `td` selector, and if so get the `cellIndex`, and it's parent node (the `tr`) `rowIndex`.

Note: the main idea here is to add a single event handler to the table, and then ignore elements that are not `td`.

```js
const table = document.createElement("table");

document.body.appendChild(table);

const width = 10;
const height = 10;

let content = "";

for (let i = 0; i < width; i++) {

  content += "<tr>";

  for (let j = 0; j < height; j++) {
    content += `<td>${i}-${j}</td>`;
  }

  content += "</tr>";
}

table.innerHTML += content;

const displayIndex = document.querySelector('#displayIndex');

table.addEventListener('mouseover', ({ target }) => {  
  if(!target.matches('td')) return;
  
  console.log({
    rowIndex: target.parentNode.rowIndex,
    cellIndex: target.cellIndex
  });
});
```

```css
td {
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your event listener inside your loop. That way you have access to iteration number.